# Como traduzir as mensagens de erro do validation summary errors asp .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, validação, asp.net-identity

Não acho um arquivo que me traga as strings de mensagem de erro para serem traduzidas, as de *annotation* estão bem, somente essas que trazem erros mais complexos, como

> Passwords must have at least one digit ('0'-'9').

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor essa parte: **as de annotation estão bem, somente essas que trazem erros mais complexos**?
De onde veio esse erro?

Comment: não há nenhum erro, preciso apenas traduzir as mensagens de erro para portugues, as do tipo '[Required]' e '[StringLength(10)]' consegui traduzir por exemplo, outras não pois não achei aonde estão

Comment: No caso estamos falando somente de Data Annotations?

Answer (score 2):

[Há um pacote NuGet que faz isso](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.pt-br/). [Os detalhes estão aqui](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=403009).

Ou você pode reimplementar o [`PasswordValidator` do ASP.NET Identity](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/85012bd0ac83548f7eab31f0585dae3836935d9d/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/PasswordValidator.cs).

---

**EDIT**

O ASP.NET Identity possui seu próprio [pacote de *resources* para o Português](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.pt-br/). Apenas instale este pacote e veja as opções de globalização do seu `web.config` que deve funcionar.

Comment: instalei o pacote, parece que devia funcionar, mas a mensagem ainda está em ingles, é relacionado a esse arquivo aqui [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/85012bd0ac83548f7eab31f0585dae3836935d9d/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/Resources.resx), vejo que existe uma dll com esse nome dentro do pacote pt-br, mas ele não está carregando o mesmo @cigano

Comment: Editei a resposta. Agora acho que deve estar dentro do que procura.